# Is mmap deterministic if ASLR is disabled?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64, mmap

If Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR) is disabled, would we have a deterministic **mmap**? By deterministic, I mean that If I run the same application again and again with the same inputs, will I get the same addresses returned by **mmap**? I am mostly interested in anonymous mmaps.

Comment: Are you asking independent of the first argument to `mmap` which is the requested address?

Comment: I am asking about anonymous mmaps.

Comment: You can request specific addresses for any kind of mapping.

Comment: Ben, I am not talking about MAP_FIXED, but when mmap is called without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR) is disabled, would we have a deterministic mmap?

If your application has exactly the same memory layout at moment of i-th mmap (in terms of which pages of virtual address space are mapped and which are not); then mmap should be deterministic in Linux kernel.

There are some strange situations possible, which can change memory layout. For example, additional command line arguments can shift stack to lower address. There are a lot of files, mmaped in c runtime (e.g. locales) and if some files have their size changed from previous start, the memory layout will be changed too. Even stack consumption may affect it.

If your application memory allocation (both sizes and order of allocations) via malloc changed, mmap will be not deterministic. So, if your application is threaded; it should fix order of malloc calls or limit all mallocs to main thread.

[mm/mmap.c: arch_get_unmapped_area](http://google.com/codesearch#iCXnLOj7beI/mm/mmap.c&exact_package=git://android.git.kernel.org/kernel/common.git&q=arch_get_unmapped_area&type=cs&l=1386) - default non-fixed mmap address resolver is deterministic IIF the VMA tree is the same AND history of previous mmap is same (there is a cache `mm->free_area_cache` which is live between calls to mmap.

Comment: Note that not only command line arguments but also the environment can shift the stack down.

Comment: Also, the AUXV vector can change; dynamic linker and any of shared library constructors.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience it is reproducible. When I have a deterministic program (written by me) (with ASLR disabled) which I run several times (with the same inputs and conditions) under `gdb`, the pointers are the same.

However, being a deterministic program is a property which is not statically detectable (I just happen to know that some programs I'm coding are deterministic enough).

Comment: Note that "deterministic program" implies no threads. Once threads are in, all bets are off. Also note that some libc facilities (e.g. aio) create threads "behind your back".

Comment: It can still be deterministic with threads if you use synchronization primitives in a way that strictly orders all allocations (including allocation of thread stacks).

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the kernel will remap the same virtual memory address multiple times. However, I wouldn't depend on the kernel to give you the same address every time because it's not required to. If you need a fixed address and you require the kernel to place it at a specific location in virtual memory, use `MAP_FIXED`.

Comment: `MAP_FIXED` is dangerous to use unless the target address range already exists in your process's address space and you know what you're replacing. Otherwise you could clobber memory that belongs to some other part of the program you don't know about!